# WebConfig & EF 6 & DbFirst & Oracle - Unable cast OracleConnection to SqlConnection

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, web-config

I'm using EF 6 with a database-first approach and Oracle. However, on connecting, the following exception is thrown:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

I'm a little confused ...

My `web.config` looks actually right:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>    
        <section name="entityFramework" 
            type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
            requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" 
                 type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TestConnection"
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Entities.PimEntities.csdl|res://*/Model.Entities.PimEntities.ssdl|res://*/Model.Entities.PimEntities.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TestDataSource;persist security info=True;user id=XXX;password=XXX&quot;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />

            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" 
                 invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
                 description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" 
                 type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
                      type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
                <dataSource alias="TestDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=TestServer.TestDomain.loc)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TestService))) " />
            </dataSources>
            <settings>
                <setting name="BindByName" value="true" />
            </settings>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

To be sure I checked my `DbContext` class:

```
public partial class TestEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSetProvider() : base("name=TestConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Seems legit.

After hours of researching I just created a new web application, imported specific nuget packages and set up ef with code first approach without generating the `.edmx` file.

This works as intended.

The used web.config for the code first approach is the same like before, except:

```
<add name="TestConnection" 
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
     connectionString="User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;Data Source=TestDataSource" />
```

Now I'm completely done.

Nothing changed except the `providerName` and of course the metadata information.

So my question is: why is Entity Framework trying to convert `OracleConnection` to `SqlConnection`?

Or how to fix my issue and using the database-first approach?

Excuse me for my imperfect English skills.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-ef-nuget-121022-2585735.txt), your connection string providerName should be the Oracle one:

```
providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
```

not the `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`